# Many to One Relationship Not Selectable

Tags: foreign-keys, relationship, directus

Using the latest docker image (8.6.2) and MySQL 5.7 with an existing database structure to test out Directus.

Trying to create a Many to One relationship between 2 collections and the option is simply not selectable.

[Many to One](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cV6w.png)

I have created a new collection and the option to add the Many to One relationship is possible but not on existing objects. This happens on all situations no matter what the 2 collections are in the relationship.

There are existing foreign keys between the tables and I have tested on FKs with and without cascades. In all situations the Many to One option is not selectable.

Any ideas ...?